# When to use ||= in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can't find any article.

I know it means "assign value to variable if variable is nil"

But.. When it is best to use it?

I did not use it before. Now after someone told me it should be used - I started to add it whenever I'm setting any instance variable.

In other words - every time I assign `@variable` in any class - I do it like so:

```
@variable ||= 'whatever'
```

Is that a good practice? Now someone told me not to use it for boolean fields.

Comment: It means "assign value to variable if variable is nil _or false or undefined_"; it's important, think about it

Comment: That's what it **does**, what it means, literally, is `@variable = @variable || 'whatever'`

Comment: You should not use this statement per default whenever you assign a variable. It is often used in cases in which a variable might be either already initialized or not. If it was initialized before, the variable keeps its old value, otherwise 'whatever' will be assigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is basically call as caching object to a variable instead frequently creating the same object. For example if you are using user variable in more than one place, it should be something like below.

```
def user
  @user ||= User.find(1)
end
```

Comment: I like the `in more than one place` part. Makes sense.